# How to send .jpg as HTTP through a TcpStream?

Tags: http, tcp, rust

I tried to write a static HTTP file server, but I'm stuck when I try to send a `.jpg` file through `TcpStream`.

Even if I `read` the file as binary, the browser doesn't seem to be able to decode the image:

```
extern crate chunked_transfer;
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::thread;
use std::fs::File;
use chunked_transfer::Encoder;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:9527").unwrap();
    println!("Listening for connections on port {}", 9527);
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(stream) => {
                thread::spawn(|| handle_client(stream));
            }
            Err(e) => println!("Unable to connect: {}", e),
        }
    }
}

fn get_path(mut stream: &TcpStream) -> String {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 4096];
    match stream.read(&mut buf) {
        Ok(_) => {
            let req_str = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf);
            let path: Vec<&str> = req_str.lines().next().unwrap().split(" ").collect();
            println!("GET {}", path[1]);
            // println!("{}", req_str);
            path[1].to_string()
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Unable to read stream: {}", e);
            "/".to_string()
        }
    }
}

fn response(path: &str, mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let file_path: &str = &("/home/xinbg/Downloads/wallpaper".to_string() + path);
    println!("{}", file_path);
    let mut buf = vec![0u8];
    let file = File::open(file_path);
    file.unwrap().read_to_end(&mut buf);

    let mut encoded: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    {
        let mut encoder = Encoder::with_chunks_size(&mut encoded, 8);
        encoder.write_all(&buf);
    }

    let headers =
        ["HTTP/1.1 200 OK", "Content-type: image/jpeg", "Transfer-Encoding: chunked", "\r\n"];
    let mut response: Vec<u8> = headers.join("\r\n")
        .to_string()
        .into_bytes();
    response.extend(encoded);

    match stream.write(&response) {
        Ok(_) => println!("Response sent"),
        Err(e) => println!("Failed sending response: {}", e),
    }
}

fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream) {
    response(&get_path(&stream), stream);
}
```

I heard that there is some kind of "HTTP server standard guide book" stuff, any idea where to find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Always fix compiler warnings**, especially ones about results you aren't using. Go back and re-read *The Rust Programming Language* chapter on [error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html) to refresh yourself on the topic.

However, that's not your problem here. I don't know what you think that `let mut buf = vec![0u8];` does, but you don't want it. That allocates a vector with exactly one value in it, an 8-bit zero. You then send that rogue byte before your JPEG, which makes it no longer valid JPEG. Removing that allows your program to work:

```
fn response(path: &str, mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let file_path = format!("/tmp/images/{}", path);

    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    let mut file = File::open(&file_path).unwrap();
    file.read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();

    let mut encoded = Vec::new();
    {
        let mut encoder = Encoder::with_chunks_size(&mut encoded, 8);
        encoder.write_all(&buf).unwrap();
    }

    let headers = [
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK",
        "Content-type: image/jpeg",
        "Transfer-Encoding: chunked",
        "\r\n"
    ];
    let mut response = headers.join("\r\n")
        .to_string()
        .into_bytes();
    response.extend(encoded);

    match stream.write(&response) {
        Ok(_) => println!("Response sent"),
        Err(e) => println!("Failed sending response: {}", e),
    }
}
```

However, your program has a **giant security hole** known as [path traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal). You should *not* expose this anywhere that has any valuable information.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable insight, I will re-read those chapters. That `[0u8]` was stupid, I thought file.read_to_end would wipe out the vector then use it as an empty one.